# invoke-rc.d on Xenial doesn't work when daemon is killed

Tags: ubuntu, init, systemd

I use an /etc/init.d script to launch a daemon. On Wheezy and Trusty even if the daemon would stop running for abnormal reasons (killed, seg fault, etc) I could start again with invoke-rc.d daemon start (or service daemon start). Also, invoke-rc.d daemon status would return with a non-zero value (I used that to in a script that would check the status of the daemon every 10 seconds and restart if it wasn't running).

Moving on to Xenial and systemd, if the daemon is killed, then invoke-rc.d daemon start doesn't work and invoke-rc.d daemon status says that the daemon is still running (exits with 0).

I know that systemd can handle init files, but it looks like this corner case is not handled properly.

In systemd you can cover this cases with SuccessExitStatus=exit_code, but not when systemd uses an init script coming from Trusty.

Any idea of how I can modify my init file cover that case on Xenial (I don't want to create an systemd file to avoid maintaining both version).

Answer (score 0):

I hear that you don't want to create a systemd `.service` file, but it will be likely be faster than what you are trying to do which is to have systemd to manage a legacy SysV init script. As you quickly discovered, the extra layer of indirection adds complexity and additional potential for bugs.

Without seeing the `init.d` script you are trying to get working, it's not immediately clear what the problem could be.

As for the time to maintain an additional version-- the file should not really need be changed at all unless something really very fundamental about the service changes over time, so the additional maintenance time should be near zero.

Key docs to check out for setting up a `.service` file are `man systemd.service`, `man systemd.unit` and possibly `man systemd.exec`. But the simplest solution is likely just to copy/paste/modify a `.service` file from a comparable service.